# parsing yaml in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, yaml

I am looking for the easiest way to using yaml with ocaml, and I am having a hard time finding a good library for doing this - since I am new to the ocaml community I would am having a hard time separating the small, not all that done, projects from the mature libraries.

What is the most production ready yaml library, and how easy is it to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Yaml rhymes with OCaml, there are no mature libraries for handling yaml in OCaml (to my personal opinion). As a first approximation I will start with [ocaml-syck](http://ocaml-syck.sourceforge.net/) library. Another option is to write yaml parser yourself, as writing parsers in OCaml is really easy, especially with `menhir`.

Comment: the sad truth is that I just started putting yaml2json into the pipeline and worked on son, but wrote yaml.. I feel to dirty :(